# Scaling up SURF lookups

Tags: sql, opencv, surf

I am currently trying to recognise DVD covers in generic photos. My initial test involved using 100 DVD covers and 10 test cases of photos that contained them, and with some tweaking of the find_obj.cpp example in OpenCV I was able to get recognition working.

However now I need to do this on a much larger database, and I am aware that the FLANN method will not scale up well to meet this requirement. How do people here recommend I scale up my SURF recognition in an SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to scale your system to several orders of magnitude, nearest neighbors search (FLANN) will not be sufficient.

In such a case what you need is to build a visual vocabulary (a.k.a [bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision)) by quantizing your descriptors, and create an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).

I recommend you to refer to the [Scalable Recognition with a Vocabulary Tree](http://www.vis.uky.edu/~stewe/publications/nister_stewenius_cvpr2006.pdf) paper that is the reference publication for such a topic.